# React-hot-loader doesn't work with React-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-hot-loader

So I've finally setup a working project with:

- Electron (`2.0.2`)
- React (`16.4.0`)
- React-router-dom (`4.2.2`)
- Webpack (`4.11.0`)
- React-hot-loader (`4.2.0`)

And just when I started to develop some react components I noticed my project won't hot reload correctly. If I adjust something on the base url (`/`) it is updated correctly, but if I update something on a secondary url, say `/test` the webpack compiles, but I get the message `Cannot GET /test`.

I've tried a lot and I cannot seem to figure out what I  am doing wrong. I looked into `react-router-dom`, since hot-reloading was an issue back in version `3.x`, but they say it should be resolved now (in `4.x` --> [It works here..](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuUBKmdeR5E)). Also i've added `<base href="/"/>` in my `index.html` so that is not it.

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?**

---

**Webpack.common.js** (This is merged into Webpack.dev.js)

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname), 'node_modules']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['env', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          env: {
            development: {
              plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel']
            },
            production: {
              presets: ['react-optimize']
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

---

**Webpack.dev.js**

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    'app': [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() // Enable hot module replacement
  ]
});
```

---

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";

import { App } from "./app";

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component/>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
};

render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./app", () => {
    render(App);
  });
}
```

---

**App.js** (my main entry point for my app, thus where I define my base routing)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Test } from './components/test';
import { Test2 } from './components/test2';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/test">Test</NavLink>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Test}/>
            <Route path="/test" component={Test2}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

*And the components 'test' and 'test2' are just plain simple react components with a 'hello world' text.*

**Anyone who sees anything that I am missing or doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this tutorial](https://medium.codylamson.com/minimum-viable-webpack-babel-react-setup-without-create-react-app-47959f43fbac) I found a way to adapt my project and get hot loading to work. It even made my code a bit cleaner and my build scripts simpeler.

---

**Webpack.common.js**

The first thing I needed to change was the babel-loader. I stole it from some tutorial, and it worked, but I did not know exactly what it did so I got rid of that code. I've also made the compilation of my code faster through the `webpack.DllReferencePlugin`.

Here is the updated webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const AddAssetHtmlPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './src/index.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['env', 'react'],
        },
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: path.join(__dirname),
      manifest: require('../dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: '<my-app-name>',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
    new AddAssetHtmlPlugin({
      filepath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/*.dll.js'),
      includeSourcemap: false // add this parameter
    })
  ],
};
```

The `AddAssetHtmlPlugin` is required since the `index.html` is dynamically created (by the [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)) for the dev server and you cannot hardcode the correct bundle import for the `vendor.dll` and the `app.bundle` ([more here](https://github.com/SimenB/add-asset-html-webpack-plugin)).

---

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    historyApiFallback: true // Allow refreshing of the page
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Enable hot reloading
  ]
});
```

What did I change:

1. I moved the entry point up to `webpack.common`.
2. I Removed the `'react-hot-loader/patch'` from the `entry`
3. (*optional*) I've added some config options for the `webpack-dev-server`.

---

**Index.js**

This is the file that caused the hot-reload to fail. Especially the `if(module.hot)` part caused it to fail. So I've changed it to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

import { App } from './app';

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <App/>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('app'),
  );
};

render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./app', () => {
    const NextApp = require('./app').default; // Get the updated code
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

The reason it works now is because now I fetch the new app and replace the old one, thus telling the hot-loader there has been a change. I could also just use `module.hot.accept()`, but that would make the `react-hot-loader` useless (you make use of the webpack hot-reloader) and this way I would also lose the state within my components every time I updated some code.

So there you go. I hope this will help anyone (other then myself).